# Creating a symlink with ansible and a list of variables

Tags: ansible

Brand new to ansible - I'm trying to symlink a bunch of files in a src directory to a destination.. Currently:

```
  file:
    src: /drupal/drush/{{ item.path }}.aliases.drushrc.php
    dest: /home/vagrant/.drush/{{ item.dest }}.aliases.drushrc.php
    with_items:
      - { path: 'new', dest: 'new' }
      - { path: 'vmdev', dest: 'vmdev' }
    state: link
```

I'm getting the error: `fatal: [vmdev] => One or more undefined variables: 'item' is undefined`

Can somebody point me in the right direction..? Cheers

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong, `with_items` should be on the same level as `file`. This is what you want:

```
file:
  src: "/drupal/drush/{{ item.path }}.aliases.drushrc.php"
  dest: "/home/vagrant/.drush/{{ item.dest }}.aliases.drushrc.php"
  state: link
with_items:
  - { path: 'new', dest: 'new' }
  - { path: 'vmdev', dest: 'vmdev' }
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: If you have issues with syntax/indentation, edit via atom + plugins: linter, ansible-linter, js-yaml-linter

Answer (score 7):

I believe your syntax is wrong. Try this:

```
file: >
  src=/drupal/drush/{{ item.path }}.aliases.drushrc.php
  dest=/home/vagrant/.drush/{{ item.dest }}.aliases.drushrc.php
  state=link
with_items:
  - { path: 'new', dest: 'new' }
  - { path: 'vmdev', dest: 'vmdev' }
```

Answer (score 4):

If both source and destination link are named same then that should be even simpler:

```
- file:
    src: /drupal/drush/{{ item }}.aliases.drushrc.php
    dest: /home/vagrant/.drush/{{ item }}.aliases.drushrc.php
    state: link
  with_items:
    - new
    - vmdev
```